Java - Incomprehensible characters instead of Cyrillic after being added to a CSV file
Using Apache Commons CSV library to generate CSV data file.
package ru.nikita;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CSVWriter {
    private final String filePath;
    private final char delimiter;

    public CSVWriter(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.delimiter = ';';
    }

    public void writeCSV(ArrayList<String> data){
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
             CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(this.delimiter))
        ) {
            csvPrinter.printRecord(data);
            csvPrinter.flush();
            csvPrinter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


I understand that I need to use utf-8 encoding, but I can't figure out how to pass this parameter for the current code.


withDelimiter is deprecated, FYI.  I doubt that is your problem, but you could try replacing it with the recommended code: CSVFormat.Builder.setDelimiter(char).

What version of Java?

Are you using a simple text editor? You should use an IDE that lets you have a look at the code you're using. As Basil wrote, you can pass a Charset to the FileWriter constructor.

Reading
Be sure to specify the character encoding within the app you use to view the CSV text file.
Files carry no metadata about the character encoding. Any text-editor, word-processor, or IDE app you use to view the text file can only guess what character encoding was used in generating the file.
You may need to find and utilize the app’s feature to explicitly instruct the app to parse the file as a UTF-8 file.
Writing
Explicitly specify UTF-8 as the character encoding when writing your CSV text file.
FileWriter uses a default character encoding.
Specify a character encoding of UTF-8.
You can use a different constructor to specify the character encoding.
FileWriter fileWriter = 
    new FileWriter
    (
        fileName ,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ,
        true
    )
;


I suggest you update your code to make use of the Files, Path, and Paths classes that arrived with Java NIO.2. You can learn more about NIO.2 in Java in this article and this article at Baeldung.com.
Notice how this example code explicitly specifies a particular character encoding.
Path path = Paths.get( "c:\\data\\myfile.txt" );
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = 
    Files.newBufferedWriter
    (
        path ,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    )
;

A BufferedWriter is an Appendable. So we can pass it to the CSVPrinter constructor.
In your code:
try 
(
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter ( Paths.get( … ) , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ;
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter( bufferedWriter , CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter( this.delimiter ) ) ;
) 
{
    …

